# AJAX to PHP without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having some trouble getting my form to submit data to my PHP file.

Without the AJAX script that I have, the form takes the user through to 'xxx.php' and submits the data on the database, however when I include this script, it prevents the page from refreshing, displays the success message, and fades in 'myDiv' but then no data appears in the database.

Any pointers in the right direction would be very much appreciated. Pulling my hair out over this one.

HTML

```
<form action='xxx.php' id='myForm' method='post'>
    <p>Your content</p> 
    <input type='text' name='content' id='content'/> 
    <input type='submit' id='subbutton' name='subbutton' value='Submit' /> 
</form>
<div id='message'></div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#subbutton").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var content = $("#content").attr('value');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "xxx.php",
                data: "content="+content,
                success: function(html){   
                    $(".myDiv").fadeTo(500, 1);
                },
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $("#message").html("<span style='color:green ! important'>Sending request.</br></br>");
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: try `var content = $("#content").val()`. also, have you checked your browser console logs to see what value is posted. also, does your php code have a `isset($_POST['submit'])` or other check that you are not sending via ajax?

Comment: When you debug, where specifically does it fail?  Does the JavaScript run without error?  Is the AJAX request made?  Does that request contain the data you expect?  Is there an error in the server-side code?  Does the server-side code see the data you expect?  Does the logic in the server-side code successfully get to the part where it tries to write to the database?  Does it have the values you expect?  And so on, and so on...

Comment: My php does have the isset($_POST['submit']. I'll try the val() out and see if it works now.

Comment: Ok, with the val() it's doing the exact same thing, which in response to you David is running with no errors on the console.

When I run the form without the AJAX the PHP delivers the values to the database perfectly fine, so I know it's an issue with the AJAX.

Comment: Can you show us the markup for `#content`?

Comment: Also, the piece of PHP code would be useful !

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information. I have edited for you this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of small changes should get you up and running. First, get the value of the input with `.val()`:

```
var content = $("#content").val();
```

You mention that you're checking to see if the submit button `isset()` but you never send its value to the PHP function. To do that you also need to get its value:

```
var submit = $('#subbutton').val();
```

Then, in your AJAX function specify the data correctly:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "xxx.php",
    data: {content:content, subbutton: submit}
    ...
```

quotes are *not* needed on the data attribute names.

On the PHP side you then check for the submit button like this -

```
if('submit' == $_POST['subbutton']) {
    // remainder of your code here
```

Content will be available in `$_POST['content']`.

Comment: You're a diamond. Thank you, this worked a treat. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the data atribute to

```
data:{
    content:$("#content").val()
}
```

Also add the atribute error to the ajax with

```
error:function(e){
   console.log(e);
 }
```

And try returning a var dump to $_POST in your php file.

And the most important add to the ajax the dataType atribute according to what You send :

```
dataType: "text" //text if You try with the var dump o json , whatever.
```

Another solution would be like :

```
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "xxxwebpage..ifyouknowhatimean",
   data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
   dataType:"text" or "json" // According to what you return in php
   success: function(data)
   {
       console.log(data); // show response from the php script.
   }
 });
```

Comment: [You shouldn't use `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: Is just an expresion haha , forget it :) *fixed

Answer (score 0):

Set the data type like this in your Ajax request: `data: { content: content }`

I think it isnt a correct JSON format.

Comment: Quotes are not required here unless it in on the *value*.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't you edit my answer? I'm on my phone and i do not have backticks.

Comment: I wasn't speaking of back ticks, I was speaking of the quotes around content.

Comment: Oh my, i see it now. Yes my mistake. Correcting it now.

Comment: Since `content` is a variable you would not need quotes around the value here either.

Comment: Corrected again, I thought this was mandatory. Thnx for correcting me.